# Django issubclass() arg 1 must be a class error in insering TabularInline at admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have these models in Django 1.5

```
class Number(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField("Patient's Number", max_length=12, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Date created", auto_now=True)
    created.editable = True

class Appointment(models.Model):
    to_number = models.ForeignKey(Number)
    message = models.CharField("Message", max_length=160)
    send_on = models.DateTimeField("Date/Time to send the message")
    email = models.CharField("Email to forward the response to", max_length=254, blank=True)
    reply_to = models.CharField("Phone number to forward the response to", max_length=12, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField("Date created", auto_now=True)
    created.editable = True

class MyLog(models.Model):
    to_number = models.CharField("To Number", max_length=12, blank=True)
    from_number = models.CharField("From Number", max_length=12, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField("Email to forward the response to", max_length=254, blank=True)
    message_id = models.CharField("Message ID", max_length=66)
    message_content = models.CharField("Message Content", max_length=160)
    message_status = models.CharField("Message status per Twilio", max_length=50)

    created = models.DateTimeField('Date created', auto_now=True)
    created.editable = True
```

I am trying to see `Appointment` as part of `Number`'s view (inline), so I follow [Django tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects) and wrote this for my `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from sms.models import Number, Appointment, MyLog

class AppointmentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Appointment
    exclude = ('created',)

class NumberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'number', 'created',)
    list_display_links = ('id',)
    list_editable = ('number',)
    search_fields = ['number']
    save_on_top = True
    readonly_fields = ('created',)
    inlines = ['AppointmentInline',] # SEEMS LIKE THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM

class AppointmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Essential Information', {
            'fields': ('to_number', 'message', 'send_on', 'reply_to', 'email'),
            'classes': ('wide', 'extrapretty')}),
        ('Non-Essential Information', {
            'fields': ('created',),
            'classes': ('collapse',)}),
        )
    list_display =  ('to_number', 'message', 'send_on', 'reply_to', 'email',)
    list_display_links = ('to_number',)
    list_editable = ('message', 'send_on', 'reply_to', 'email',)
    search_fields = ['to_number__number', 'message', 'reply_to', 'email']
    save_on_top = True
    readonly_fields = ('created',)

class MyLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('to_number', 'from_number', 'email', 'message_content', 'message_status', 'created',)
    fields = ('to_number', 'from_number', 'email', 'message_content', 'message_status', 'created',)
    search_fields = ['to_number', 'from_number', 'email', 'message_content', 'message_status']
    readonly_fields = ('to_number', 'from_number', 'email', 'message_content', 'message_status', 'created',)

admin.site.register(Number, NumberAdmin)
admin.site.register(Appointment, AppointmentAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyLog, MyLogAdmin)
```

But now I am getting the following error whenever I try to view `Number` via admin page:

```
TypeError at /admin/sms/number/
...
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Exception Location:     /home/phyo/.virtualenvs/t4stest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/validation.py in validate, line 179
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/uwsgi
```

I'm new to Django and have looked around the internet (Googled) quite a bit to figure out what I'm doing wrong here to cause such error. But I still couldn't figure this out after struggling with it for a few hours. If someone could help me explain what mistake I'm making here, I would really appreciate it. My goal is to be able to see related `Appointment` entries whenever I view `Number` via Django admin page. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

inlines can't be a string, ie. use this:

```
inlines = [AppointmentInline,]
```

instead of:

```
inlines = ['AppointmentInline',]
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a silly and newbie mistake that I made. :) Fixed it and it works like charm. Also, if you are an expert in Django admin and model design, could you (@yedpodtrzitko) please take a quick look at [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340693/django-model-advice-for-chained-foreignkeys-approach) I have about listing chained, ForeignKey relationships in Django admin console? Thank you again!